# Finnished copying files to usb but its still copying even though it finnished copying

Tags: usb

In currently running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I keep getting a problem where the computer is finished copying the files but it still tells me its copying the files, I've tried to eject it but it keeps corrupting my USB drive, is there any other way to copy the files into the USB? or do you guys have a solution to my problem?

[image: IMAGE OF PROBLEM]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory hardware can be very slow in USB pendrives (even if there is a USB 3 interface). [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed) and links from it can help you find fast USB 3 pendrives.

After a number of write operations many USB pendrives will get slow. They can be restored to almost the original speed, if you overwrite the whole drive with zeros according to [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297).

---

When the user interface indicates that the copying has finished, data may still be in a buffer in RAM, and it may take long to finish flushing the buffer.

You can run the command `sync` in a terminal window. When `sync` finishes, the window will return to prompt, and it should be OK to unmount/eject the drive and after that you can unplug it without risk.

---

If you suspect that there is some error, and that the copying/writing process has stopped, you can use `iotop`. Install it with

```
sudo apt install iotop
```

and run it in a terminal window with

```
sudo iotop -o
```

and you will see how much is read and written, and which programs/processes are responsible for it.